# Get an activity's ResolveInfo object knowing it's name?

Tags: java, android

I want to add my activity (com.myapp.launcher.settings) to an empty ArrayList.

```
    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> selectedApps = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
    selectedApps.add(/*WHAT GOES IN HERE?*/);
```

But I don't know how to get a ResolveInfo object with my activity.

---

I managed to make a workaround that loops through all apps to find my activity. But it's not very efficient or practical:

```
    // Get an array list of all apps
    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> allApps = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for(final ResolveInfo app : allApps) {
        // If it's name is "com.myapp.launcher.settings" add it
        if(app.activityInfo.name.equals("com.myapp.launcher.settings")) {
                selectedApps.add(app);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [`resolveActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) with an explicit `Intent`. Probably something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.myapp", "com.myapp.launcher.settings"));
ResolveInfo app = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
selectedApps.add(app);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another answer in the event you don't know only the `packageName` of the application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage(packageName);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
ResolveInfo result = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
```